# What kind of setting Hudson need to detect changes in ClearCase dynamic views?

Tags: hudson, clearcase

How would you configure Hudson to only execute Build or Post Build actions if changes in Clear case dynamic view are detected?

Answer (score 2):

With the [ClearCase Plugin for Hudson](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/ClearCase+Plugin), you can use snapshot and dynamic views.

I prefer using *existing* dynamic views:

[image]
<sub>(source: [hudson-ci.org](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/download/attachments/2916537/base_dynamic_config.png?version=1&modificationDate=1252713598000))</sub>

I define my dynamic view on a slave and define my job to be executed on that slave.

---

Note: for dynamics views that are created by Hudson, the trick is "load rules are required" (even though load rules are normally reserved for snapshot views).

> Specify one or more load rules - this is required, even with a dynamic view.
> **The load rules are used both for determining the contents of snapshot views and for constructing the "cleartool lshistory" command used for polling and generating changelogs.**

So when you want Build and Post Build actions on changes, you need to have defined your load rules on your dynamic view setting, in order for the `cleartool lshistory` to accurately determine if there are any changes on said dynamic view.